# Is it possible to start an ASP.Net 5 application in an application with C#?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, owin, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing an application for embedded devices and we want to add remote access to the device. ASP.Net 5 looks very attractive as it advocates that it can be self hosted.

I had a look of a few blogs (e.g http://blog.tomasjansson.com/asp-net-5-self-hosting-the-application/) and found one can run a mvc project from command line outside of IIS. But is it possible to host the mvc project in a C# application without invoking it from command line?

Following the blog, I added this command to project.json.

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
},
```

It looks like the assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting has the actual code hosting the mvc app. But I could not find any document about it.

Appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: What .net framework are you using in your embedded device?

Comment: @alisabzevari We use .Net framwork 4.6 on embeded windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a temporary solution to run mvc6 in my application.

First, publish the application to output dir of the c# solution. Then, I create a new process to invoke the command to start the mvc6 app. The problem with this is the mvc6 runs in separate app domain with my c# app and I have to use other inter process communication techniques to bridge the two.

The code is as below:

```
string appDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string mvcProjectPath = appDir + @"\DirOfPublishedMVC";

        _process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, FileName = "web.cmd", WorkingDirectory = mvcProjectPath };
        _process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        _process.Start();
```

web.cmd is generated by the publish command which is defined in project.json commands section.